# Simplified rectangle packing algorithm. Being able to pick from bigger pool of shapes.

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bin-packing

I have a rectangle with 200 width and 100 height. I have a mix pool of 50 rectangles and boxes. The rectangles comes in shapes like 20x40, and 40x20. The boxes will come in shapes of 20x20 and 40x40. So lets say If I want to fit the highest number of boxes and rectangles in this bigger rectangle in order to leave no space. How I can achieve it other that bin packing algorithm or rectangle packing algorithm. And if I should pick one of those algorithms, is there a good implementation out there for this scenario ?

Comment: In this question, you have an array of #boxes, right?

Comment: Do you mean these exact values? Divide everything by 20. You have rectangles 1x2, 1x1, and 2x2 which you want to fit into a larger 10x5 rectangle? Lay out the 2x2's along the 10 axis until you have used them all up, then layout the 1x2 rectangles parallel to the 10 axis in the same manner, then do the same with the 1x1s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we can abstract the problem a little bit:

A table with 10*5 grids. And we fill the table with 1*1,1*2,2*1(1*2 and 2*1 is considered the same?),2*2 tiles.

We can ignore the 1*1 because it's can fit into any cases.

If the we consider 1*2 and 2*1 is the same:

This case is somehow simple.Just put 2*2 together. Then we wiil get:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxx....
xxxxxx....
..........
```

we just put 1*2 in such a way:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxAABB
xxxxxxCCDD
EEFFGGHHII
```

You can check that strategy works for any cases.

If 1*2 or 2*1 is not consider the same?

Then it will be a little bit complex. Maybe there exists a elegant solution like above, but it's hard to find and prove. Considering the table is some how small we can just do a complete search with some pruning and I think it will be works.

Comment: I dont think 1x2 and 2x1 are equal in this question